# javascript for loop exit early

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

below is a simple function. It's adds all number in the array and store in a variable. The problem is, the loop execute just once even though the condition for exiting the loop was not met. Am I missing something here?

```js
const numChecker = (...args) => {
  let x = args;
  let y;
  let i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
      if ((typeof x[i]) === "number") {
      y += x[i];
      }
      return y;
    }
 }

console.log(numChecker("A", "B", "C", 100, 300, 200));
```

Comment: Because of `i < x.length - 1`??

Comment: you are using return inside the loop ... that  returns out of your function ... so of course it only runs once

Answer (score 1):

**There are 3 issues with your code :-**

1. First is `let y;`.
2. Second is `i < x.length - 1`.
3. You're doing `return y` at wrong place.

In the first issue, when you declare a variable like this `let y`, then the `typeof(y)` is undefined. Here, you want to store the `sum of numbers`, so the variable `y` must be of type `number`. So, you must declare and initialize it like `let y = 0`;

In 2nd one, in the loop, the array will be parsed to 2nd last element. `x[4]` in your case. So, the condition in the loop should be like `i < x.length`.

In the last, you must `return y` outside the loop, so that the sum will be printed on the `console` will be of all the `numbers` in the `array`.

**Check the Snippet below.**

```js
const numChecker = (...args) => {
  let x = args;
  let y = 0;
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if ((typeof x[i]) === "number") {
      y += x[i];
    }
  }
  return y;
}

console.log(numChecker("A", "B", "C", 100, 300, 200));
```

Hope, it will solve your issue.

Comment: Welcome, @AldrinEspinosa